# how to create design of Text within right arrow symbol with html and css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to create a simple design with the help of bootstrap, html and css the design is look like:
[image]

i have tried following code to design:
html:

```
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                
                <ul class="list-unstyled lists">
                    <li>Initial Meeting</li>
                    <li>Pre Test</li>
                    <li>Application for Job</li>
                    <li>Legal Screening</li>
                    <li>Additional Processing</li>
                    <li>Schedule for Training</li>
                </ul>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and css is:

```
.container{
   margin-top:200px;
 }
 .lists{
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.lists li{
 background:#e1ddd3;
 color:#333;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani', sans-serif;
 font-stretch: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 line-height: 1.5;
 letter-spacing: normal;
 height: 40px;
 position: relative;
 margin:10px;
 padding:10px 20px;
}
.lists li:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 right: -20px;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 20px solid #e1ddd3;
 border-top: 20px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

but unable to give background line which is behind of list-items, please anyone have a look on this and suggest a solution for above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pseudo element on `.lists`.

```css
.container{
   margin-top:200px;
 }
 .lists{
    /*border:1px solid #000;*/
    position: relative;
}
.lists li{
 background:#e1ddd3;
 color:#333;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani', sans-serif;
 font-stretch: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 line-height: 1.5;
 letter-spacing: normal;
 height: 40px;
 position: relative;
 margin:10px;
 padding:10px 20px;
}
.lists li:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 right: -20px;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 20px solid #e1ddd3;
 border-top: 20px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}


.lists::before {
    content: '';
    width: 80%;
    height: 110%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5%;
    left: 10%;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8">
                
                <ul class="list-unstyled lists">
                    <li>Initial Meeting</li>
                    <li>Pre Test</li>
                    <li>Application for Job</li>
                    <li>Legal Screening</li>
                    <li>Additional Processing</li>
                    <li>Schedule for Training</li>
                </ul>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an absolute position pseudo element `:after` the `.lists`. For example:

```
.lists:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: -10px;
    left: 40px;
    height: 105%;
    width: 75%;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

[Codeply](https://codeply.com/p/7NRkj32n5D)